# How to commit only the files that are different to existing github remote repository?

Tags: git, github

Not sure how to make this question more precise so i'll explain.

I've got my remote repository on github with few commits.
I did download last commit and made some changes in few files in my local project but i deleted git repository in my project.

When i want to hook up my local project to existing github repo using :

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:User/UserRepo.git
```

my local files won't compare with last commit but it wants to push every file i've got in project (files i didn't changed that are already on my last remote commit), not just the few files I changed.

How to compare my local changes with last remote commit and only commit changes that are different or new from last commit?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a another way to do it :

if you want to commit your files on top of a branch named `mybranch` :

1. create a local branch, with no history, named `mybranch` :

   ```
   git branch mybranch
   git checkout mybranch
   ```
2. run `git fetch`, to update your view of `origin/mybranch`
3. run `git reset origin/mybranch`
   *important* : do *not* use the `--hard` option, this would throw away your local modifications

You are now back to a state where :

- the active commit is the head commit of `mybranch`
- your local changes are compared to this commit

You may want to add `git branch -u origin/mybranch` to have your local branch track the remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that git will always compare your working copy against the commit you currently have checked out, which will normally be the tip of some branch. So to compare against some other state, you need to check out that state, and apply your changes on top of it.

The situation you describe is slightly unusual, because you've run `git init` (creating a completely new repository) where `git clone` would be more natural (starting the repository based on the remote one).

The good thing is, git doesn't really care about that - although often used with a central server, it's designed to be entirely distributed, so linking unrelated repositories together is no problem.

You need to do a few things:

1. Fetch the contents of the remote repository with `git fetch origin` (`git clone` would have done this by default, but `git remote add` does not).
2. Move your local files out of the way - the easiest way is to probably just move *all* of them to a completely different folder on your local machine, since git currently thinks they're all brand new.
3. Check out the branch you want to continue working on; this is probably called `master`, or `main`, or `develop`, but those are just conventions.

- If you run `git checkout master` and *don't already have a branch called master*, git will treat it as short for `git checkout -t origin/master`, meaning "create a local branch `master` associated for `push` and `pull` with the branch of the same name on the `origin` remote".
- If you *already have a local branch* with the name of the branch you want (e.g. it was created for you by `git init`), the easiest approach will be to delete it - check out any other branch, then run `git branch -D branch_name`.

4. Now move your files back into the working directory, and they will be compared against the branch you checked out.

Comment: hey, thanks a lot for helping me out! I've got a problem though with your solution, project is pretty big and there is a lot of local changes/additions that iam not aware of, and its not possible for me to move changed files to another folder because i'am not sure which ones are changed. Is there another way to do this? I can just delete git folder i initialized and do it another way if it is possible. Basically i want to hook up to origin branch that is last comitted without deleting my local changes. Is it even possible?

Comment: @PTK: IMSoP suggests you to move *all* your files away, run git checkout, then move *all* of them back. It is `git`'s job to spot which files were modified.